# Schengen visa question – Indian citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, georgia-country

I am an Indian citizen. I will leave India in January 2015 and plan to be travelling through Asia for about 10 months. I will then be in Georgia. My plan is to apply for a German Schengen visa in Georgia and then enter the EU/Schengen zone via Turkey → Greece. My major stay will be in Germany.

Do you think it is possible for me to apply for a Schengen visa at the German Embassy in Georgia? I am an Indian citizen and will have been out of India for about 10 months.
Normally the rule is that I can only apply from my country of residence and 3 months prior to scheduled arrival in the EU/Schengen country.

Comment: Are you planning to go to Germany? You should apply at the embassy for the country you are visiting.

Comment: If you know you will be visiting Germany, why not apply for a visa now from India?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to do this. Here's why? You have two further potential questions (read: problems): first, you will need to prove to the embassy that why you didn't apply while you were in the home country? This is simply because the embassy will require your proof of residence in the country i.e., from where you are applying. This will also include many supporting documents such as residence status, bank statement, utility bills, etc - essentially, you should contact the embassy, and ideally get the application form and make sure you understand you will have all the documents (as i listed only some of them here). In some case, the embassy will not grant the visa to non-residents. Second, for Schengen zone, you need to apply to the Schengen country from where you enter the Schengen zone OR the country where you will spend most of your time i.e. main destination.